# Fullscreen mode in google chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, fullscreen

I am stuck with fullscreen modes. although in mozzilla page is showing as it should. but as i go with chrome in fullscreen mode background colors are not showing.Here's my code

```
        $('.button').on('click', function(){  
        var elem = document.getElementById('mainContainer_preview');  
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full-screen pseudo class (for webkit and mozila) :

```
:-webkit-full-screen {
  /* css rules for full screen */
  background: #fff; /* or whatever color you need */
}
:-moz-full-screen {
  /* css rules for full screen */
}
```

See [this Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) and [this David Walsh article](http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen) for usage

From the above Mozilla article:

> It's worth noting a key difference here between the Gecko and WebKit
>   implementations at this time: Gecko automatically adds CSS rules to
>   the element to stretch it to fill the screen: "width: 100%; height:
>   100%". WebKit doesn't do this; instead, it centers the fullscreen
>   element at the same size in a screen that's otherwise black. **To get
>   the same fullscreen behavior in WebKit, you need to add your own
>   "width: 100%; height: 100%;" CSS rules to the element yourself**:

Comment: To get the same fullscreen behavior in WebKit, you need to add your own "width: 100%; height: 100%;".this was the stinking thing

Comment: but the hell is that whole page is getting opened in fullscreen not the div i want

Comment: Try targeting the div you need like this: elem = document.getElementById('#div_name'); then in css: :-webkit-full-screen #div_name